# Ionic + Firebase Push notification Error Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification

I've installed the Ionic1 and created a new empty project. Adding the android platform, it builds. Then adding the FCM plugin and the necessary google-services.json.
Cordova CLI : 6.1.1
PLugin
https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm

[image]

SDK last version

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`.

Comment: try it but same error

Answer (score 1):

first step to solve your error make sure that google packages are up to date

[image: Android SDK manager]